# MySQL WHERE IN (substrings of a string)?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT customerID, name, email
FROM Customers
WHERE customerID IN (substrings delineated by spaces of CID string)
```

Where what I want to happen, is it returns the entries that have a matching customerID.

Unfortunately, the value CID is a string of all the matching CIDs separated by spaces. I've tried to change it to be some sort of list, but no luck on that end. If I could use something like string splitter that would solve my problem, but it doesn't seem to be available in MySQL.

Sorry for the relatively simple question, but an hour of googling has returned no clear answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is `like`:

```
SELECT customerID, name, email
FROM Customers
WHERE CONCAT(' ', CID, ' ') LIKE concat('% ', customerID, ' %') ;
```

I really do advocate that you separate the string.  If it is coming from a table, then you probably need a junction/association table.

Comment: Concat only works for two arguments at once, can I just use WHERE (' ' || #CID || ' ') LIKE ('% ' || customerID || ' %') ?

Comment: @JRHB . . . MySQL has no limit at all on the number of arguments that it takes:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat.  If you have an issue with `concat()` only taking two arguments then you're question is mistagged.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you could use the `REPLACE` function:

```
SELECT customerID, name, email
FROM Customers
WHERE customerID IN (REPLACE(CID string,' ',','))
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: The return from `REPLACE` would be a single scalar value. The syntax is valid, but in terms of looking for a `customerID` in the list, this isn't going to work with the `IN` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`WHERE FIND_IN_SET(CustomerID, REPLACE(spacedList, ' ', ',')) > 0`

[FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

You might need to also cast CustomerID to a char, but I would try without the cast first.